# Best way to run multiple database commands over website

Tags: php, html, ajax, pdo

I currently have a website with a visual representation of a database table.
Here i can make some changes, and when i click on a button "export/execute", the changes will be made in the database (lets say remove entry (DELETE) and create new entry (INSERT) with updated data).

Herefore i would have to run A LOT of SQL INSERT instructions (to give you an example each TD you see here has to be inserted)

**What is the most logical / efficient way to do this?**

What i thought of:
Things would make it easier and i think clearer if i could somehow make a list of PHP functions that would be run one by one .

Example:

```
DeleteStation(WP006)
CreateStationDevices(WP006)
CreateDeviceDB(WP006,LSD01,D,DK002,WP00601,RIS-VLAANDEREN,NOODSTOP ALSB,0,0,0,0,0,0,)
INSERT INTO device ( stationame, statdevi, dvtype, refname, imgname,responsible, textnr, pollst, i_bedmaz, i_bedzzu, i_sigzma, i_sizgzu, i_awerztf,i_alarzm, i_plaus_minz, i_plaus_maxz, i_ala_min, i_ala_max, i_reference, record, extratext,quittype) VALUES ('WP006','LSD01','D','DK002','WP00601','RIS',12572,0,0,2,0,2, 0,'N',0,0,0,0,0,0,'','M')
CreatePunktDB(WP006,LSD01,28,9,1,S,100)
CreateDeviceDB(WP006,LSD02,D,DK002,WP00601,RIS,NOODSTOP OMLOOPRIOLEN,0,0,0,0,0,0,)
```

Where (for example) DeleteStation would be a function that executes the DELETE instruction for given paramater.

1. Is this even possible ? How would i pass DeleteStation to PHP AND have it executed? 
   Ajax probably but i'm wondering how i could run the functions via ajax :s

[image]

Comment: I suppose you could send the instructions as a single string using ajax and then parse them using PHP which then calls the functions?

Comment: Can you explain or give example: 'and then parse them using PHP'

Comment: What I meant was to split the string down into instructions at the PHP end ... so for example if you added a semi-colon to the end of each instruction you could split the string on that, then use regular expressions or some other pattern/command matching to compare against each string and break it down to the point where you recognise the command and it's parameters, so that you can then call the equivalent function, passing in the parameters.

Comment: You could use the PHP explode syntax effectively for much of what I've said ... split on line endings to get an array of commands, then loop through those, splitting on opening bracket, to seperate parameters from command, then strip off the closing bracket from the parameters and split those by the comma to gain an array of parameters which you can then send to the recognised function ... is that making sense?